# missing concrete implementation of state.build

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error in Dart:
"Missing concrete implementation of "state.build""

The first method is the following:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // String titleInput;
  // String amountInput;
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [
    // Transaction(
    //   id: "t1",
    //   title: "New Shoes",
    //   amount: 69.99,
    //   date: DateTime.now(),
    // ),
    // Transaction(
    //   id: "t2",
    //   title: "Weekly Groceries",
    //   amount: 16.53,
    //   date: DateTime.now(),
    // ),
  ];
```

Does anyone knows what this error means and how to solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a `build` method to the `State` of your widget, this method *describes the part of the user interface represented by your widget*, e.g.,
(add this to the `MyHomePageState`)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 100,
              color:  Colors.yellow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Check the **curly brace** that closes the **class** where the **Widget build** method is found. You might just have closed it in the wrong place.

This was the case for me.

So make sure your build method is within the curly braces that enclose the class

```
class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the `Stateful widgets` and `Stateless widgets` should have `build` method.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       ...
    );
}
```

If you want to use it without `build` do not extend the class with `State`, use it like

```
class YourClassName {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto the definitation of `State<T>` class and see what are the abstract methods. You will find `build()` method as the only abstract method i.e. a method without body. So when yu are inheriting from `State<MyHomePage>`, you must override the `build()` and give a body; basically you will create your `Widgets` inside the `build()` method.

So to fix the error add the below code to your class:

```
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold( // Your Widget
         ...
      );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check

```
@override
Widget build( Buildcontext context)
{ 
return Container();
}
```

Check spelling of build

reason : As u extend your class with stateless or statefull widget , U use overiding method to over ride  the **pre defined method** which is already written in parent **class which is
state less/full class**