# Getting "Missing concrete implementation of State.build" Error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am receiving the error "Missing concrete implementation of State.build" when attempting to run this code for Angela Yu's FLutter course:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/location.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoadingScreenState();
  }
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }
}

void getLocation() async {
  Location location = Location();
  await location.getCurrentLocation();
  print(location.latitude);
  print(location.longitude);
}

void getData() async {
  Response response = await get(
      'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02');
  print(response);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

I have tried the responses related to this question:

[missing concrete implementation of state.build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63246564/missing-concrete-implementation-of-state-build)

...but have not had any success. Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your enclosing brackets are wrong. Try to delete the ```} ``` character just below ```initState``` and put on the end of the file. All of the methods must be *inside* of the ```_LoadingScreenState ```class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enter code hereYou have a extra }  after

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }
```

Delete it

And another missed above

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
```

Check your  { }

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the response. Apologies if this is a dumb question, but what do the curly braces actually "mean?" I've been taking this course, and I feel like I'm learning a lot about the mechanics of coding, but not much about what all of the symbols and syntax actually represent. Do you have any good resources that you'd recommend?

Comment: There is no dumb question.
the curly braces in many programming langues mean the scope of variables effect 
like when you use int x = 10; so this effects only through its scope 
i.e main (){ int x = 5; }  void ontherFun(){ int x = 10 ;} 

Angela course is good, but you need to practice more only then this concepts will be concentrated in your mind

Comment: the best way to practice to find the problems like that

Comment: Thanks again! If you have any other resources that you'd suggest, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Max course if very good for intermediate level you can find it in Udemy also, but i recommend to practice enough(by making applications with problems) before start it

Answer (score 0):

Check your {}. This error mainly comes due to the missing of {} or using extra {}.