# missing concrete implementation of state.build 'StatefulWidget.createState'

Tags: android, flutter

i can't  run my application
the error message ==> Missing concrete implementation of 'StatefulWidget.createState'.

```
class myhomepage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     home: DataFromApi(),
   ) ;
  }

}

class DataFromApi extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _DataFromApiState creatState()=> _DataFromApiState();

}
```

Comment: Welcome, Please share how have you created the `_DataFromApiState` class?

Comment: Is that "creatState()" a is a typing error also in your codes? Make it "createState()".

Answer (score 0):

Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63246603/14434426:

You need to add a build method to the State of your widget, this method describes the part of the user interface represented by your widget, e.g., (add this to the MyHomePageState)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:
            Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 100,
              color:  Colors.yellow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```