# How to fix error: Missing concrete implementation of 'State.build'

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter home_screen I have the following:

```
class DataFromAPI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataFromAPIState createState() => _DataFromAPIState();
}
 
class _DataFromAPIState extends State<DataFromAPI> {
  Future getUserData() async {
    var url = Uri.http("...");
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(response.body);
    print(jsonData);
  }
}
 
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
```

Why do I keep getting `State.build` error while there is already one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [missing concrete implementation of state.build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63246564/missing-concrete-implementation-of-state-build)

Comment: There is no ``build`` method in the ``_DataFromAPIState`` class ! You have one for the``HomeScreen`` class. Also, move the ``getUserData()`` method to the ``HomeScreen`` class and remove the ``DataFromAPI`` class.

Comment: @OMiShah Thank u but i already have a Widget what will happen to the initial widget when i create a new one? Could you type answer to clarify your comment with explanation

Comment: what you're saying is not clear to me. What widget do you have already? What do you mean by what will happen when you create one?

Comment: The 1st widget related to the home screen.